# How can I bypass the object to get the specific data?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion

I have a object with values: { key: '', value: '', type: '' }. I need to realize formatter, which output tree from input data in output data. Please help me, because i can`t understand how i can do it, and please explain the answer. Please if you know any books or sites where i can understand objects, arrays, js. Thanks very much.

INPUT data:

```
         const el = [
            {
             "key": "common",
             "value": [
              {
               "key": "follow",
               "value": false,
               "type": "added"
              },
              {
               "key": "setting1",
               "value1": "Value 1",
               "value2": "Value 1",
               "type": "nochanged"
              },
              {
               "key": "setting2",
               "value": 200,
               "type": "deleted"
              },
              {
               "key": "setting3",
               "value1": true,
               "value2": null,
               "type": "changed"
              },
              {
               "key": "setting4",
               "value": "blah blah",
               "type": "added"
              },
              {
               "key": "setting5",
               "value": {
                "key5": "value5"
               },
               "type": "added"
              },
              {
               "key": "setting6",
               "value": [
                {
                 "key": "doge",
                 "value": [
                  {
                   "key": "wow",
                   "value1": "",
                   "value2": "so much",
                   "type": "changed"
                  }
                 ],
                 "type": "object"
                },
                {
                 "key": "key",
                 "value1": "value",
                 "value2": "value",
                 "type": "nochanged"
                },
                {
                 "key": "ops",
                 "value": "vops",
                 "type": "added"
                }
               ],
               "type": "object"
              }
             ],
             "type": "object"
            },
            {
             "key": "group1",
             "value": [
              {
               "key": "baz",
               "value1": "bas",
               "value2": "bars",
               "type": "changed"
              },
              {
               "key": "foo",
               "value1": "bar",
               "value2": "bar",
               "type": "nochanged"
              },
              {
               "key": "nest",
               "value1": {
                "key": "value"
               },
               "value2": "str",
               "type": "changed"
              }
             ],
             "type": "object"
            },
            {
             "key": "group2",
             "value": {
              "abc": 12345,
              "deep": {
               "id": 45
              }
             },
             "type": "deleted"
            },
            {
             "key": "group3",
             "value": {
              "deep": {
               "id": {
                "number": 45
               }
              },
              "fee": 100500
             },
             "type": "added"
            }
           ]
```

OUTPUT data:

```
            {
               common: {
                 + follow: false
                   setting1: Value 1
                 - setting2: 200
                 - setting3: true
                 + setting3: null
                 + setting4: blah blah
                 + setting5: {
                       key5: value5
                   }
                   setting6: {
                       doge: {
                         - wow: 
                         + wow: so much
                       }
                       key: value
                     + ops: vops
                   }
               }
               group1: {
                 - baz: bas
                 + baz: bars
                   foo: bar
                 - nest: {
                       key: value
                   }
                 + nest: str
               }
             - group2: {
                   abc: 12345
                   deep: {
                       id: 45
                   }
               }
             + group3: {
                   deep: {
                       id: {
                           number: 45
                       }
                   }
                   fee: 100500
               }
           }
```

I tried call function with recursive, but i don`t know what do next.

```
const stylish = (data, replacer = ' ', spacesCount = 1) => {
  const iter = (data, depth) => {
  const arr = [];
  const keys = Object.keys(data);
  const sizeBefore = depth * spacesCount;
  const replacerBefore = replacer.repeat(sizeBefore);
  keys.forEach((key) => {
    if (data[key].type === 'object') {
      arr.push(`${replacerBefore}  ${data[key].key} : ${iter(data[key].value)}`);
    } if (data[key].type === 'added') {
      arr.push(`${replacerBefore}+ ${data[key].key} : ${iter(data[key].value)}`);
    } if (data[key].type === 'deleted') {
      arr.push(`${replacerBefore}- ${data[key].key} : ${iter(data[key].value)}`);
    } if (data[key].type === 'changed') {
      arr.push(`${replacerBefore}- ${data[key].key} : ${data[key].value1}`);
      arr.push(`${replacerBefore}+ ${data[key].key} : ${data[key].value2}`);
    } if (data[key].type === 'nochanged') {
      arr.push(`${replacerBefore}  ${data[key].key} : ${data[key].value2}`);
    }
  });
  return [
    '{',
    ...arr,
    '}'
    ].join('\n');
};
```

What i get with my code:

```
Output:

{
   common : {
+ follow : {
}
  setting1 : Value 1
- setting2 : {
}
- setting3 : true
+ setting3 : null
+ setting4 : {
}
+ setting5 : {
}
  setting6 : {
  doge : {
- wow : 
+ wow : so much
}
  key : value
+ ops : {
}
}
}
   group1 : {
- baz : bas
+ baz : bars
  foo : bar
- nest : [object Object]
+ nest : str
}
 - group2 : {
}
 + group3 : {
}
}
```

Comment: Your question is not clear to me. Could you split up the input data, the array with changes and the output data?

Comment: @Wimanicesir i fixed code, please tell me if you don`t understand code..

Comment: You seem to be trying to do pretty-printing, but it seems you forgot to increment the indentation depth ("spacesCount"). You're also not indenting the closing `}` (the opening `{` will be indented by the caller already).

Comment: @Luatic yes, you are right, but i don`t know how make increment the identation depth. Maybe you cah give advice? I think what need add depth, but how

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When dealing with complex data structures, just separate processing of different types of elements so that you can handle each type with dedicated logic.

In your case you have `objects` which describe changes to the structure. And you have `contents` which is a raw payload of those changes.

So when you encounter `object`, nested items can be both `object` and `content` (the letter is every entry that is not `"type": "object"`). Process them further with corresponding routines.

And when you encounter `content`, it is either a primitive value that can be written to the output as is; or it is an instance of `Array` or `Object` whose items are basically nested `contents`.

Obviously, in order to maintain proper indenting, it is necessary to keep track of the current nesting level at every point of processing.

---

I did this demo for the sake of practice. It can detect errors in the structure and add them to the output (first call) or silently skip (second call).

```js
const input = [
    {
        "key": "common",
        "value": [
            {
                "key": "follow",
                "value": false,
                "type": "added"
            },
            {
                "key": "setting1",
                "value1": "Value 1",
                "value2": "Value 1",
                "type": "nochanged"
            },
            {
                "key": "setting2",
                "value": 200,
                "type": "deleted"
            },
            {
                "key": "setting3",
                "value1": true,
                "value2": null,
                "type": "changed"
            },
            {
                "key": "setting4",
                "value": "blah blah",
                "type": "added"
            },
            {
                "key": "setting5",
                "value": { "key5": "value5" },
                "type": "added"
            },
            {
                "key": "setting6",
                "value": [
                    {
                        "key": "doge",
                        "value": [
                            {
                                "key": "wow",
                                "value1": "",
                                "value2": "so much",
                                "type": "changed"
                            }
                        ],
                        "type": "object"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "key",
                        "value1": "value",
                        "value2": "value",
                        "type": "nochanged"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "ops",
                        "value": "vops",
                        "type": "added"
                    }
                ],
                "type": "object"
            }
        ],
        "type": "object"
    },
    {
        "key": "group1",
        "value": [
            {
                "key": "baz",
                "value1": "bas",
                "value2": "bars",
                "type": "changed"
            },
            {
                "key": "foo",
                "value1": "bar",
                "value2": "bar",
                "type": "nochanged"
            },
            {
                "key": "nest",
                "value1": { "key": "value" },
                "value2": "str",
                "type": "changed"
            }
        ],
        "type": "object"
    },
    {
        "key": "group2",
        "value": { "abc": 12345, "deep": { "id": 45 } },
        "type": "deleted"
    },
    {
        "key": "group3",
        "value": { "deep": { "id": { "number": 45 } }, "fee": 100500 },
        "type": "added"
    },
    {
        "key": "RIDICULOUSLY-NESTED-ARRAY",
        "value1": [[[[[['BOOM!']]]]]],
        "value2": [[[[[['BOOM!']]]]]],
        "type": "nochanged"
    },
    {
        "key": "CUSTOM-OBJECT",
        "value": {
            "EMPTY-OBJECT": {},
            "EMPTY-ARRAY": [],
            "ARRAY-OF-PRIMITIVES": [ 100, 200, 300 ],
            "ARRAY-OF-ARRAYS": [
                [ "Alice", "Bob" ],
                [ "Kent", "Jessica" ]
            ],
            "ARRAY-OF-OBJECTS": [
                { "aaa": 111, "bbb": 222, "ccc": 333 },
                { "ddd": 444, "eee": 555, "fff": 666 }
            ],
            "COMPLEX-ARRAY": [
                "next item is empty array", [],
                "next item is empty object", {},
                {
                    "ggg": { "YES": "NO" },
                    "hhh": [ true, false ],
                    "iii": 10000000000000000111111110222203333n
                },
                null
            ]
        },
        "type": "added"
    },
    "INVALID ENTRY",
    {
        "key": ["INVALID KEY"]
    },
    {
        "key": "TEST-INVALID-TYPE",
        "type": "INVALID TYPE"
    },
    {
        "key": "TEST-INVALID-OBJECT",
        "value": "INVALID OBJECT",
        "type": "object"
    },
    {
        "key": "TEST-EMPTY-OBJECT",
        "value": [],
        "type": "object"
    }
];

function stylish (input, includeErrors) {

    function writeNewline (string, level, sign) {
        output += sign
            ? `\n${'    '.repeat(level - 1)}  ${sign} ${string}`
            : `\n${'    '.repeat(level)}${string}`;
    }

    function writeError (message, level) {
        if (level) {
            writeNewline(`ERROR: ${message}`, level, '!');
        }
        else {
            output += `ERROR: ${message}`;
        }
    }

    function writeNested (brackets, level, callback) {
        output += brackets[0];
        let savedLength = output.length;
        callback();
        if (savedLength == output.length) {
            output += brackets[1];
        }
        else {
            writeNewline(brackets[1], level);
        }
    }

    function processContent (input, level) {

        if (Array.isArray(input)) {
            writeNested('[]', level, () => {
                input.forEach((item) => {
                    writeNewline('', level + 1);
                    processContent(item, level + 1);
                });
            });
        }

        else if (typeof input == 'object' && input != null) {
            writeNested('{}', level, () => {
                Object.entries(input).forEach(([key, value]) => {
                    writeNewline(key + ': ', level + 1);
                    processContent(value, level + 1);
                });
            });
        }

        else {
            output += input;
        }
    }

    function processObjectEntry (input, level) {
        if (typeof input == 'object' && input != null) {

            let key = input.key;
            if (typeof key != 'string') {
                if (includeErrors) {
                    writeError('invalid <key> of entry', level);
                }
                return;
            }
            let prefix = key + ': ';

            switch (input.type) {
            case 'object':
                if (Array.isArray(input.value)) {
                    writeNewline(prefix, level);
                    processObject(input.value, level);
                }
                else if (includeErrors) {
                    writeError(`entry "${key}" -> <value> has to be an array`, level);
                }
                break;

            case 'added':
                writeNewline(prefix, level, '+');
                processContent(input.value, level);
                break;

            case 'deleted':
                writeNewline(prefix, level, '-');
                processContent(input.value, level);
                break;

            case 'changed':
                writeNewline(prefix, level, '-');
                processContent(input.value1, level);
                writeNewline(prefix, level, '+');
                processContent(input.value2, level);
                break;

            case 'nochanged':
                writeNewline(prefix, level);
                processContent(input.value1, level);
                break;

            default:
                if (includeErrors) {
                    writeError(`entry "${key}" -> invalid <type>`, level);
                }
            }
        }

        else if (includeErrors) {
            writeError('entry has to be an object', level);
        }
    }

    function processObject (input, level) {
        writeNested('{}', level, () => {
            input.forEach((item) => processObjectEntry(item, level + 1));
        });
    }

    let output = '';
    if (Array.isArray(input)) {
        processObject(input, 0);
    }
    else if (includeErrors) {
        writeError('input has to be an array');
    }
    return output;
}

console.log(stylish(input, true));
console.log(stylish(input));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: please tell me how can I become like you? You very progessional, you really master . Thank you very much, but also i can\`t understand this code, because i can`t programming in this level, how programming you.

Comment: @Sabir Nah, I'm not a master, just had a few hours to do something. Here on StackOverflow thousands of people do like that. :)

Comment: @Sabir I'd recommend you actually try again and implement from scratch the simplest version: no validation, no indentation, no collapse of empty brackets, just write every item on its own line. Make separate methods for `"type": "object"` and those other entries with raw values. Once it works, add indentation. Then add another feature, etc. If you think you're struggling, make a pause, come back later. It takes more time and effort when you lack skill. But everything boils down to learning and practicing. Solve problems, and your skills will gradually grow. We all go through this process.

Comment: @Sabir Hey, just to notify: there was a bug with indentation in `nochanged` entries. If you're using my code, find `case 'nochanged':`, and remove `+ 1` from `processContent(input.value1, level + 1);`

Comment: thank you very much. i tryed do it